# Change from ManyToMany to OneToMany Blazor ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, blazor, .net-5

I was trying to save data in OneToMany table (One Advert, many Tags). But I ended up making a working ManyToMany relation case while using a good resource. How would I recreate It from start based on what I have achieved so far? There are some things I could not fully understand in my ManyToMany case, therefore changing is a bit difficult.

Snippet from Advert model:

```
public class Advert
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<AdvertTag> AdvertTag { get; set; } = new List<AdvertTag>();
}
```

Tag model(I am not sure what `if (obj is Tag p2)...` does:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AdvertTag> AdvertTag { get; set; } = new List<AdvertTag>();

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Tag p2)
        {
            return Id == p2.Id;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In my Form component I am saving data likes this:

```
try
{
    await advertRepository.CreateAd(advert);
}
```

I attach related Tags. And I think `{ TagId = x.Id }` passes ID of related Tag (which already exists in DB):

```
    private async Task OnDataAnnotationsValidated()
    {
        Advert.AdvertTag = SelectedTags
            .Select(x => new AdvertTag { TagId = x.Id }).ToList();

        await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(null);
    }
```

`AdvertController` makes the job and saves Advert and puts ids of both Advert and Tag into an intermediate table. I think entity framework somehow knows about the relation and saves the correct Tags, because no Tags mentioned in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Post(Advert advert)
    {
        context.Add(advert);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return advert.Id;
    }
```

`ApplicationDbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AdvertTag>().HasKey(x => new { x.AdvertId, x.TagId });
}

public DbSet<Advert> Adverts { get; set; }
public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public DbSet<AdvertTag> AdvertsTags {get; set;}
```

So far I wrote a new  Tag model, which includes AdvertId:

```
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AdvertId {get; set; }
    public Advert Advert {get; set;}
}
```

And added one line to Advert model:

```
public List<Tag> Items { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();
```

And this line to ApplicationDbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasKey(x => new { x.AdvertId});
```

I am not sure how to pass id of Advert that I am creating to Tags table:

```
public List<Tag> SelectedItems { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();
...

try
{
    advert.Tags = SelectedItems;
    await advertRepository.CreateAd(advert);
}
```

I get these errors:

1. Tags IDs appear in AdvertId column.
2. Advert ID appear in new column that Entity Framework created itself AdvertId1.